# Defining my own React event types

Tags: javascript, npm, reactjs, webpack

I am using React for a mobile web project. To provide better interactivity, I've modified `TapEventPlugin` with a different implementation of `touchTap`, as well as defined a new event simulating hovering over an element.

To integrate this with React, I have forked the project and added `TapEventPlugin` into the `ReactInjection.EventPluginHub.injectEventPluginsByName` call in ReactDefaultInjection.js. This works fine if I want to `grunt build` a version of React with my changes, but I now want to bundle React with my application into a single JS file, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

Ideally, I'd like to stop forking and use the vanilla npm React with some way of hooking in my new events from my application. Is this possible?

Alternately, I could specify the URL for my React fork as a dependency in my package.json, but the package.json in the root of the React project is for react-tools, not React. Is there some way to trigger a grunt build and use the build/npm-react folder as a dependency as part of the `npm install` process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run `grunt build:npm-react` then you can `npm install` or `npm link` from the `build/npm-react/` folder.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It works, but I have to remember to keep them in sync everywhere. Ideally, I'd like to get away from maintaining a React fork, though.

Comment: Right, I realize this is a pain. Eventually we'd like to come up with a supported plugin API that doesn't require rebuilding React to take advantage of.